# tkinter splash screen code doesn't show image

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to show a splash screen image when i start my program. It appears to import the size of the splash screen image but not actually show the image of the splash screen. I've tried using the image in various formats (.png, .gif, .jpeg, etc.) but and a few other sample code blocks i found but i'm thinking its something obvious i'm not seeing considering its importing the size of the image. Appreciate any help you can provide.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

image_file = 'splash.gif'
image = tk.PhotoImage(rootFolder, file=image_file)

x = int((width / 2) - (image.width() / 2))
y = int((height / 2) - (image.height() / 2))
geometry = '{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(image.width(), image.height(), x, y)

root.geometry(geometry)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.create_image(0,0, image=image, anchor='nw')


root.after(3000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the canvas so that it will be visible.